# How Can i control the 'total' output in 'ls -l' command?

Tags: shell-script, shell, ls, touch

the question is, how can control the `ls -l` `total` output ?
first impression with example that give us `total = 0`

```
els3@els3PC:~/test$ touch file
els3@els3PC:~/test$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 els3 els3 0 Jul 20 12:05 file
```

As i mention this example give us this result `total = 0` by creating empty file.

in other way I will try to create a non empty file2 contain '3ls3' .

```
els3@els3PC:~/test$ cat > file2
3ls3
^C
els3@els3PC:~/test$ cat file2
3ls3
els3@els3PC:~/test$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 els3 els3 5 Jul 20 12:11 file2
```

this second example give us `total 4` by creating a non empty file.
the hole Q is how can i get for e.g `total 1` or `total 2` etc.. by creating a new file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man ls`:

```
In addition, for each directory whose contents are displayed, the total number of 
512-byte  blocks used by the files in the directory is displayed on a line by 
itself, immediately before the information for the files in the directory.
```

The minimum number of blocks allocated to a file depends on OS, file system type etc, so there is no direct way to influence the number shown.

Comment: This doesn’t change your point, but the block size varies from one operating system to another, it’s not always 512 bytes.

Comment: @StephenKitt True, one more parameter which can't easily be influenced by the user :-)

Comment: ... except with GNU `ls` and its `--block-size` option ;-).